# Compare value between row and increment another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table with a column A with a value smallint and I want compare if the value is greater than a last value in a same table. If this value is greater, I want increment a value in a column B.

Before request :

| Id | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 0 |
| 2 | 400 | 0 |
| 3 | 400 | 0 |
| 4 | 500 | 0 |
| 5 | 550 | 0 |

After request :

| Id | Column A | Column B | Column DiffValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 400 | 1 | 100 |
| 3 | 400 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 500 | 2 | 100 |
| 5 | 550 | 3 | 50 |

Actually I have this code for compared the value between two row but I'm blocked now.. Code :

```
UPDATE tA
SET tA.DiffValue =tB.DiffValue,
FROM MyTable as tA
INNER JOIN(
        SELECT Id, DiffValue = A - LAG(A) OVER (ORDER BY A ASC)
        FROM MyTable 
        ) as tB ON tA.Id = tB.Id
```

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: A SUM running aggregate should solve it for you. Something like: `select * from (select sum(flag) over(order by id) as running, * from (select case when lag(a) < a then 1 else 0 end as flag, * from yourtable) x) x) x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @siggemannen it's a good answer, I just change 'when lag(a) < a by 'DiffValue > 0'

```
select * from (select sum(flag) over(order by id) as running, * from (select case when DiffValue > 0 then 1 else 0 end as flag, * from yourtable) x) x) x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a running conditional `COUNT` over the `LAG`. You seem to be using the wrong `ORDER BY` column, you need `ORDER BY Id`. And then update the CTE directly, you don't need to rejoin.

```sql
WITH PrevValues AS (
    SELECT mt.*, 
      Diff = mt.A - LAG(mt.A) OVER (ORDER BY mt.Id)
    FROM MyTable mt
),
Counted AS (
    SELECT t.*,
      Count = COUNT(CASE WHEN DiffValue > 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY t.Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM PrevValues t
)
UPDATE Counted
SET DiffValue = Diff,
    ColumnB = Count;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, I compose an SQL for a similar situation.

```
Select *
INTO #Tmp1
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
           [Column A],
           [Column B],
           LAG([Column A], 1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) Prev_Value
    from table1
) A

UPDATE t1
SET t1.[Column DiffValue] = (ISNULL(t2.[Column A] - t2.Prev_Value, 0))
FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN #Tmp1 t2
        ON t1.ID = t2.ID
drop table if exists #Tmp1

select * from table1
```

Another Example without using Temporary table.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[Column DiffValue] = t2.Diff_Value
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID,
           [Column A],
           [Column B],
           (ISNULL([Column A]-LAG([Column A], 1) OVER (ORDER BY ID),0)) Diff_Value
    from table1
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID

SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: In version 2, why rejoin, why not update `t2` directly?

Comment: also, this answer doesn't handle Column B update

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**